# Why will the loop in my allSubStrings function not work?

Tags: python, list, function

I am trying to write a Python program that has two functions. The first finds all substrings of a word with a given length and adds them to a list (i.e. "hello" with x = 3 would return 'hel', 'ell', 'llo'). The second function uses this to find all possible substrings in a word. However, whenever I run it through a loop, the second function does not work. Can someone try to explain why?

```
def subString(string, x):
    cutList = []
    j = 0
    i = 0

    while(j < 1):
        sliceText = slice(i, i + x)
        cut = string[sliceText]
        if (len(cut) == x):
            cutList.append(cut)
        else:
            j += 5
        i = i + 1
    
    return cutList

def allSubStrings(string):
    fullList = []

    for k in range(len(string)):

        tempList = subString(string, k)
        fullList.extend(tempList)
        print(k)

    return fullList
```

Comment: Why do you call `slice()` instead of just writing `cut = string[i:i+x]`?

Comment: @Alexander I realized that, I changed my question.

Comment: What is `j` used for? Why is it incremented by 5?

Comment: The `while` loop can be replaced with `cutList = [string[i:i+x] for i in range(0, len(string)-x)]`

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `subString()` goes into an infinite loop when `x == 0`, because `len(cut) == 0` will always be true. Since you don't need zero-length substrings, the loop in `allSubStrings()` should use `range(1, len(string))`.

```
def subString(string, x):
    return [string[i:i+x] for i in range(len(string)-x)]

def allSubStrings(string):
    fullList = []

    for k in range(1, len(string)):

        tempList = subString(string, k)
        fullList.extend(tempList)
        print(k)

    return fullList

print(allSubStrings("abcdefgh"))
```

Output is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'de', 'ef', 'fg', 'abc', 'bcd', 'cde', 'def', 'efg', 'abcd', 'bcde', 'cdef', 'defg', 'abcde', 'bcdef', 'cdefg', 'abcdef', 'bcdefg', 'abcdefg']
```